# interpret results of cassandra stress test

Tags: performance, cassandra, scylla, cassandra-stress-tool

We have scylla cluster with tree node. Each node is in its own datacenter. Тo evaluate cluster performance i use cassandra stress test with this parameters:

```
cassandra-stress write "no-warmup  cl=QUORUM" -rate threads=1 -schema "replication(strategy=NetworkTopologyStrategy, DC1=1, DC2=1, DC3=1)" -mode cql3 native connectionsPerHost=80 protocolVersion=4 user=cassandra password=cassandra -node 10.0.0.3
```

Result:

```
type       total ops,    op/s,    pk/s,   row/s,    mean,     med,     .95,     .99,    .999,     max,   time,   stderr, errors,  gc: #,  max ms,  sum ms,  sdv ms,      mb
total,            84,      84,      84,      84,    10.3,     5.0,    45.8,    59.3,    65.9,    65.9,    1.0,  0.00000,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           145,      61,      61,      61,    16.3,     5.5,    45.1,    46.2,    47.2,    47.2,    2.0,  0.11899,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           197,      52,      52,      52,    19.3,     5.4,    44.5,    46.0,    46.7,    46.7,    3.0,  0.12423,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           258,      61,      61,      61,    15.9,     5.3,    44.2,    44.4,    46.0,    46.0,    4.0,  0.09670,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           325,      67,      67,      67,    15.3,     5.1,    45.4,    46.7,    47.0,    47.0,    5.0,  0.07708,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           388,      63,      63,      63,    15.9,     5.2,    44.3,    46.2,    47.9,    47.9,    6.0,  0.06482,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           455,      67,      67,      67,    14.8,     5.3,    46.0,    46.3,    46.5,    46.5,    7.0,  0.05547,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           518,      63,      63,      63,    15.5,     5.3,    44.0,    46.2,    46.9,    46.9,    8.0,  0.04891,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           576,      58,      58,      58,    17.2,     5.3,    45.3,    45.8,    48.0,    48.0,    9.0,  0.04541,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           634,      58,      58,      58,    17.0,     5.3,    44.4,    46.1,    46.2,    46.2,   10.0,  0.04231,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           704,      70,      70,      70,    14.3,     4.8,    44.1,    46.6,    46.6,    46.6,   11.0,  0.03908,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           775,      71,      71,      71,    14.4,     4.8,    43.8,    44.1,    46.7,    46.7,   12.0,  0.03650,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           847,      72,      72,      72,    13.5,     5.0,    41.7,    44.2,    45.7,    45.7,   13.0,  0.03438,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           914,      67,      67,      67,    15.1,     5.1,    43.8,    43.9,    44.1,    44.1,   14.0,  0.03191,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,           972,      58,      58,      58,    17.0,     5.1,    45.7,    46.6,    47.1,    47.1,   15.0,  0.03089,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1031,      59,      59,      59,    17.0,     4.9,    44.2,    44.8,    45.9,    45.9,   16.0,  0.02966,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1085,      54,      54,      54,    18.7,     4.8,    44.0,    44.1,    44.7,    44.7,   17.0,  0.02975,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1165,      80,      80,      80,    12.1,     4.7,    43.8,    44.3,    45.6,    45.6,   18.0,  0.03075,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1224,      59,      59,      59,    17.3,     5.2,    43.9,    46.9,    46.9,    46.9,   19.0,  0.02963,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1294,      70,      70,      70,    14.2,     4.8,    43.9,    44.3,    46.4,    46.4,   20.0,  0.02833,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1363,      69,      69,      69,    14.2,     4.7,    44.2,    46.7,    46.8,    46.8,   21.0,  0.02707,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1432,      69,      69,      69,    14.3,     4.9,    44.0,    44.3,    48.2,    48.2,   22.0,  0.02591,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1494,      62,      62,      62,    16.3,     4.9,    44.3,    46.8,    47.3,    47.3,   23.0,  0.02492,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1557,      63,      63,      63,    15.7,     5.5,    45.4,    47.3,    47.4,    47.4,   24.0,  0.02395,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1620,      63,      63,      63,    16.2,     5.0,    45.2,    46.6,    46.9,    46.9,   25.0,  0.02305,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1687,      67,      67,      67,    14.9,     4.8,    44.1,    45.5,    45.6,    45.6,   26.0,  0.02216,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1743,      56,      56,      56,    17.8,     4.8,    44.0,    46.3,    47.3,    47.3,   27.0,  0.02203,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1804,      61,      61,      61,    16.0,     4.8,    43.8,    44.4,    45.4,    45.4,   28.0,  0.02138,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1877,      73,      73,      73,    13.5,     4.8,    44.1,    44.5,    44.8,    44.8,   29.0,  0.02101,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          1941,      64,      64,      64,    15.9,     5.0,    44.0,    46.7,    47.3,    47.3,   30.0,  0.02032,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          2003,      62,      62,      62,    16.0,     4.8,    44.0,    44.1,    44.2,    44.2,   31.0,  0.01975,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,          2004,     215,     215,     215,    16.9,    16.9,    16.9,    16.9,    16.9,    16.9,   31.0,  0.07564,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
```

As we see, we have a relatively small mead and mean latency, but catastrophic .95 and .99 latency.
And main question: why? And why this values so different?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a goo practice to have a single node per data center. It could be the source of latency. You also run a single thread in the client but that's more of a throughput issue. There are no details about the machines you run. Try to replicate one of the published benchmarks of Scylla

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we are limited to 3 nodes at the moment. And to ensure availability, they were placed in different DCs. The test is run in one thread as dictated by the features of our software. The main question is why is there such a big difference between med/mean and 0.95/0.99 latency